# ASP.NET Web Service on localhost?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, asp.net-mvc-4

At the minute I am building an ASP.NET MVC application to learn the technology, and I want to incorporate web services as I have never used them before and I want to have experience with them.

I was wondering would it be possible to create a web service and run it on the Visual studio local host along with my MVC application an then consume it with the MVC application.
I am hoping that the web service will basically pull data from the the same db as the app and then allow the mvc app to consume the service. Would this be possible?

Sorry if this is a pointless question but it is for a college project. Any help greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very possible with Visual Studio - in fact, it is easy.  Best to follow some tutorials - one such tutorial is http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store.

For more specifics about the service from within VS, this link may be more helpful - msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668184(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: There's a *lot* of information at that link.  Can you be a little more specific than saying "yes, it's possible" and linking him to a firehose?

Comment: "Would this be possible?" was the only question posted.  There is a lot in the post as well, MVC, ASP.NET, services.  The link covers the various items in the post.

Comment: @MikeWeber It is a bit hard to find what's relevant to the question given the massive amount of information in that post, especially if you don't know what you're looking for. Maybe you could drill down and link to a specific part of the post?

Comment: You are both correct, after I re-read the post, I realize the concern is for the service, instead of ASP.NET and MVC in general.  For more specifics about the service from within VS, this link may be more helpful - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668184(v=vs.100).aspx sorry to have provided a link to a firehose (good analogy).  This one is based on 2010, and uses the northwind DB.  Other versions of VS can be selected.

Comment: @MikeWeber +1 for the update, this is much more relevant. Although you should edit your original question with the link instead of adding it as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking a WCF service, this is very easy to do. You'll want to add the service to the same solution as your MVC project, right click on References in the MVC project, then click add service reference. On the dialog that comes up, click discover to the right and it will find the service in the solution allowing you to add it locally.

Once you have a service reference, you can right click and configure to see the path. Should be set to localhost in this case. Doing this will allow you to set breakpoints and debug the service through your MVC application.